# Bing Maps .v7 How to reference pushpins with links outside of the map?

Tags: bing-api, bing-maps

I have a Bing Map in which I have a set of pushpins, with InfoBoxes associated with each one.  I am using v7.

I'd like have a link that is outside the map to display a particular pushpin's Infobox. How can this be done?

example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
 <style type="text/css">
  /* Define a style used for infoboxes */
  .NSIMInfoBox 
  {
   position: absolute;
   border: solid 2px black;
   background-color: White;
   z-index: 1000;
   padding: 5px;
   width: 250px;
   visibility: visible;
  }
  #mapDiv 
    {
    position: relative;
    top: 20;
    left: 20;
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    border: solid 2px #555;
    }
 </style>
<script charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0">

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>

</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        getMap();
    });

    var pinInfobox = null;
    var map;
    var pin;

    function getMap() {
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"),
            { credentials: "apikey",
                center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(45.5, -122.5),
                zoom: 10,
                showScaleBar: true,
                mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road
            });


        //          //Multiple locations
        //          var polygonWithPins = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
        var loc1 = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(45.5, -122.5);
        var loc2 = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(45.6, -122.5);

        pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(loc1);
        //Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'click', displayEventInfo);
        pin.setInfoBox(new InfoBox("<strong>Pushpin Number1!</strong>"));
        map.entities.push(pin)

        var pin2 = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(loc2);
        pin2.setInfoBox(new InfoBox("<strong>Pushpin Number 2!</strong>"));
        map.entities.push(pin2)


    }

        function InfoBox(html) {
            this.div;
            this.html = html;
        }

        InfoBox.prototype.show = function (e) {
            if (this.div == undefined) {
                //Create container div
                this.div = document.createElement("div");
                this.div.className = "NSIMInfoBox";
                this.div.innerHTML = createInfoBox(this.html);
                this.div.style.display = "";
                var mapDiv = document.getElementById('mapDiv');
                mapDiv.appendChild(this.div);
            }

            var pinLocation = map.tryLocationToPixel(e.target.getLocation(), Microsoft.Maps.PixelReference.control);

            this.div.style.left = pinLocation.x + "px";
            this.div.style.top = pinLocation.y + "px";
            this.div.style.visibility = "visible";
            this.div.style.display = "block";
        };

        InfoBox.prototype.hide = function (e) {
            if (this.div != undefined) {
                this.div.style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
        };

        //Extend pushpinclass
        Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin.prototype.setInfoBox = function (infoBox) {
            if (typeof this.infoBox != undefined && this.infoBox != undefined && this.infoBox != null) {
                this.removeInfoBox();
            }

            // Add handlers for mouse events
            this.mouseoverHandler = Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(this, 'click',
            function (e) { infoBox.show(e); }
           );
            this.mouseoutHander = Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(this, 'mouseleave',
            function (e) { infoBox.hide(e); }
           );
        };

        // Extend the Pushpin class to remove an existing InfoBox object
        Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin.prototype.removeInfoBox = function () {
            this.infoBox = null;

            // Remove handlers for mouse events
            Microsoft.Maps.Events.removeHandler(this.mouseoverHandler);
            Microsoft.Maps.Events.removeHandler(this.mouseoutHander);
        }

        function createInfoBox(html) {
            var myHtml;
            myHtml = '<div style="text-align:right; margin-right: 5px;" onclick="closeInfoBox();">x</div>' +
                '<div style="padding: 5px;">' + html + '</div>';

            return myHtml;
        }

        function closeInfoBox() {
            $('.NSIMInfoBox').hide();
        }


</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mapDiv" class="map"></div>
    <span class="click">click me!  - HERE I WANT TO SHOW THE FIRST PIN'S INFOBOX</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I was able to solve this problem -

Since I pushed the pins into the EntityCollection, I was able to reference the pushpin by parsing through the collection, then calling the invoke method in order to get the result I was looking for:

Sample:

```
            var newpin = map.entities.get(i);
            Microsoft.Maps.Events.invoke(newpin, 'click', '');
```

Comment: What should i need to pass from here `<span class="click">click me!  - HERE I WANT TO SHOW THE FIRST PIN'S INFOBOX</span>` to above Sample: in order to open infobox.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but I would hope it can work. Essentially you can simulate the mouse events over a pushpin object.

First, when creating a pushpin, be sure to set a class name on the resulting  by setting the typeName property on the pushpin options object. This will allow you get hold of the resulting div by using the css selector #mapDiv div..

Then you can create an event and dispatch it on the div, which will indicate to the map control that it should show the information associated with the pushpin. Since you're using jQuery, I think it would be something along the lines of (in response to the click event on your link that is outside the map control):

```
// assuming the typeName you used was "foo"
$('#mapDiv div.foo').trigger($.event('mousemove'));
```

You might have to try issuing mouseover before/instead of the mousemove. Also this is a general idea of a potential approach ... hopefully it yields in a solution.